# Does a foreign key need to reference a primary key or candidate key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am having two conflicting definitions of foreign key.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

`the foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary key in the first table.`

From my lecture notes:

`Foreign key does not have to match a primary key but must match a candidate key in some relation`

Which is which? Does a foreign key need to reference a primary key or candidate key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the relational model of data, a foreign key must reference a candidate key.

In almost all SQL dbms, a foreign key must reference a candidate key.

In MySQL, [a foreign key can reference just about anything](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed for performance reasons. However, **the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL**.

Emphasis added.

This is a Bad Thing, IMHO.

Comment: Support for inclusion dependency constraints is a *good* thing. The *syntax* is "bad" because it calls the constraint a foreign key when it isn't.

Comment: @sqlvogel: Their docs say "The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys." It looks to me that the MySQL developers did a bad implementation of foreign key constraints rather than a good implementation of inclusion constraints. Wouldn't all operations on an inclusion constraint have to be well-defined?

Comment: SQL FKs reference UNIQUE, analogous to superkey, not CK.

Answer (score 4):

The rule that a FK must reference a "primary" key was imposed by the older versions of the SQL standard.  That rule has been relaxed by now (and it is now permitted for a FK to reference any candidate key), but it may be the case that some products still go by the old rule, just as it may be the case that some textbooks or other sources have not yet been updated to reflect the new state of affairs.

I don't know precisely *when* the rule was relaxed in the standard, but imo it must certainly have been no later than 2003.

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key must refer to an unique key (a primary key is unique), because if it doesn't, it cans be the reference of 2 lines, and it's just impossible for a foreign key. Then you can have your primary key, but an unique key who is not a primary key and do a foreign key on it. And your unique key must be `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Foreign keys have to be linked to candidate keys because, if join between tables was made using foreign key, the FK linked to an attribute that was not a candidate key could result in multiple values being retrieved where only one value should be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, the foreign key has nothing to do with the primary key tag of another table, if it points to a unique column (not necessarily a primary key) of another table then too, it would be a foreign key. So, a correct definition of the foreign key would be:
**Foreign keys are the columns of a table that points to the candidate key of another table**.